# Unable to get access token using Spotify API

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios, spotify

I am trying to implement Spotify API in my web site.

First I am redirecting user to:

```
>! const authEndpoint = "https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize";
>! const clientID= {my client id}         
>! const redirectUri = "http://localhost:3000/dashboard";
>! const scopes = ["user-library-read"];
>! 
>! export const loginEndpoint = `${authEndpoint}?          client_id=${clientID}&redirect_uri=${redirectUri}&scope=${scopes.join(
>!     '%20'
>! )}&response_type=code&code_challenge_method=S256&code_challenge=your-generated-code-challenge`;
```

and then extracting the code:

```
>! useEffect(() => {
>! const fetchToken = async () => {
>! const hash = window.location.hash;
>! const code = hash.split("=")[1];
>! 
>! if (code) {
>! const response = await getToken(code);
>! const accessToken = response.access_token;
>! 
>! setToken(accessToken);
>! setClientToken(accessToken);
>!         }
>!     };
```

and then passing code to the function to get token:

```
>! export const getToken = async (code) => {
>! const tokenEndpoint = 'https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token';
>! 
>! const response = await axios.post(
>! tokenEndpoint,
>! new URLSearchParams({
>! code: code,
>! redirect_uri: redirectUri,
>! grant_type: 'authorization_code'
>!         }),
>!         {
>! headers: {
>!             'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
>!         },
>!       }
>!     );
>! console.log(response)
>! 
>! return response.data;
>! };
```

But I am not getting the token and it is giving axios error 400.

Can someone help me.

Trying to get access token from Spotify API but getting 400 error